# Searching for an item in a dataset and showing it in a combo box

Tags: c#

I have done combobox binding on form load.
I want to load  ComboBox with numerous products, then based on a bar code i 'd like to select the corresponding product in the ComboBox.

Comment: Add a WHERE clause to your SQL statement?

Comment: This code is for adding all items in the barcode if i will use the where statement then all the other values will be removed from the combo box.
i need all the values in the combo box while show only the selected value in combo box .

Comment: Maybe you need to make your question clearer, then.  If you want the product WHERE barcode matches your scanned barcode, then simply add a WHERE condition to the existing SQL statement.

Comment: Like we use combox1.SelectedItem="test";
i need to run this type of code for combo box binded with dataset

Comment: Do some research on SQL Server query parameterization, and cascading combo boxes.  You'll find everything you need there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you were looking for this:

```
DataTable products = new DataTable();
products.Columns.Add("Product_Name");
products.Columns.Add("Product_BarCode");

products.Rows.Add("test1", 123456);
products.Rows.Add("test", 923456);
products.Rows.Add("test8", 823456);
products.Rows.Add("test", 723456);
products.Rows.Add("test0", 023456);

productname_tb.DataSource = products;
productname_tb.DisplayMember = "Product_Name";
productname_tb.ValueMember = "Product_BarCode";

// select the "test8" item by using it's Product_BarCode value of 823456
for (int i = 0; i < productname_tb.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (((System.Data.DataRowView)(productname_tb.Items[i])).Row.ItemArray[1].ToString() == "823456")
    {
        productname_tb.SelectedItem = productname_tb.Items[i];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This code works
for (int i = 0; i < Product_Name.Items.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (((System.Data.DataRowView)(Product_Name.Items[i])).Row.ItemArray[1].ToString() == "panadol")
                            Product_Name.SelectedItem = Product_Name.Items[i];
                    }

Is there any more fast way instead of loop

Comment: Yes, we could break the loop once the value it's found.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want to load your `ComboBox` with numerous products, then based on a bar code you'd like to select the corresponding product in the `ComboBox`.  Try the following:

```
productname_tb.Items.IndexOf("<YOUR BARCODE>");
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: That's part of it.  He'll need a query that parameterizes the resulting value from the combobox into a WHERE clause.

Comment: The error after using this code is this "Data is null can not use this type of code on null"
I have editied your code like this  productname_tb.Items.IndexOf(productbc_tb.Text);

Comment: @Robert Harvey That only applies if he doesn't want the list to contain all products with only the particular product selected.  A WHERE would limit the combobox to only 1 item.

Comment: productbc_tb is a textbox which countains barcode of which i need item